# Result of calling strcpy is different than expected

Tags: c, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char src[]="123456";
   strcpy(src, &src[1]);
   printf("Final copied string : %s\n", src);
}
```

When I use the *Visual Studio 6 Compiler* it gives me the expected answer "`23456`".

How come this program prints "`23556`" when compiled with *gcc 4.7.2*?

Comment: undefined behaviour, use memmov() instead

Comment: how did you come with the fact that it where an overlap ?

&Src[1]="23456" right !?! so where is the overlap ?

Comment: @PeterMiehle Yes, memmov plus an extra `e`.

Comment: `src` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array `src`. `&src[1]` is a pointer to the second element of the array. As the source-string is not of length 0, they obviously overlap.

Comment: this means I have to copy from another string "`char dest[]="123456";`" and do "`strcpy(src, &dest[1]);`"

Comment: src = source = from, dst = destination = to

Comment: I'm asking my self after reading your question again: What is the "expected answer" for undefined behavior? How you can expect even any answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`strcpy(src, &src[1]);` is undefined behavior:

> #### C11 §7.24.2.3 The `strcpy` function
>
> The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` (including the terminating null
>   character) into the array pointed to by `s1`. **If copying takes place between objects that
>   overlap, the behavior is undefined.**

By the way, `memcpy` is similar (but not `memmove`). See [C FAQ: What's the difference between `memcpy` and `memmove`](http://c-faq.com/ansi/memmove.html).

Comment: Hmm... seems to be similar to the `memcpy` vs `memmove` issue.

Comment: Where do you find these information's? And how do you find them so quickly? OR have you written your own book :D?

Comment: So this means that the VS compiler is srtonguer for the undefined behaviour or does the coder had a undefined reflexion to write such ligne ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I have a copy of the C standard draft nearby, if that's what you are asking :). See [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/1009479).

Comment: @Rizier123: On my system, it is described in the glibc manpages (`man 3 strcpy`): The  strings  may  not overlap.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: It's undefined behaviour, the implementation can do whatever it pleases.

Comment: Even the 1988 K&R (ANSI) C has this in the first paragraph of Appendix B3 regarding string functions.  Any proper C book documents this.

Answer (score 3):

From ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 (c99)

> 7.21.2.3 The strcpy function
>
> Synopsis
>
> 1
>
> `#include <string.h>`
>
> `char *strncpy(char * restrict s1,`
>   `const char * restrict s2,`
>   `size_t n);`
>
> Description
>
> 2 The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null
>   character) into the array pointed to by s1. **If copying takes place between objects that
>   overlap, the behavior is undefined.**

So what you are doing is simply undefined behaving ;)

You can also see the ANNEX J.2

Stating cases of undefined behavior with a note how to prevent:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

[...]

> —An attempt is made to copy an object to an overlapping object by use of a library
>   function, other than as explicitly allowed (e.g., memmove) (clause 7).

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behaviour. Use the `memmove` function instead. `memmove` is designed to allow overlapping of source and destination buffers.

```
memmove(src, &src[1], strlen(&src[1]) + 1) ;  // + 1 for copying the terminating zero
```

Comment: Yes the memory overlaps.

Comment: Instead of the awkward looking `&src[1]`, you can use `src+1` for clarity.

Comment: @Jongware you are right, but I left it the same as in the original question on purpose.